# Sort a list of ListViewItems

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, listview

I need to write a method to sort the list of listview items - listOfLVI. 
Given - The number of elements in the list (or maxLines) could be thousands. That's why Virtual list view is considered.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static int maxLines = 5;

    System.Collections.Generic.List<ListViewItem> listOfLVI = new List<ListViewItem>();
    ListViewItem NewListViewItem = null;

    // Populate Items
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.VirtualMode = true;
        listView.VirtualListSize = maxLines;
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = maxLines.ToString();

        for (int l = 0; l < maxLines; l++)
        {
            NewListViewItem = new ListViewItem("TestName " + l + "NG");
            listOfLVI.Add(NewListViewItem);
        }
    }

    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi = listOfLVI[e.ItemIndex];

        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        lvsi.Text = lvi.Text;
        lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);

        e.Item = lvi;
    }

    // Add Item
    private void AddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("maxLines: " + maxLines);
        int count = maxLines;
        for (int l = count; l < (count + 5); l++)
        {
            NewListViewItem = new ListViewItem("TestName " + l + "FZZ");
            listOfLVI.Add(NewListViewItem);
            maxLines = maxLines + 1;
        }

        foreach (ListViewItem each in listOfLVI)
        {
            String eachString = each.Text;
        }

        // Need to sort the list now based on TestName.
        listOfLVI.Sort(); 

        listView.VirtualListSize = maxLines;
    }

    // Sort List
}
```

Can anyone help me write code to sort the given list of listview items? Would QuickSort algo be a good choice here? If yes, any suggestions on how can we implement that?

Comment: You can hand array.Sort pretty much any array and any Comparer and it will give you a sorted array. Of course you are dealing with Sorting/ordering in context of a GUI. Totally other approaches might be nesseary. Unfortunately I only know how to do this in WPF, so someone else would have to help you.

Comment: Short question: Why do you want to sort ListViewItems instead of data?

Comment: @MaciejLos - How exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: It depends on what is a ListView datasource...